# Zero Deployment for Entity Framework with SQL Compact

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, code-first

I strungle with the deployment of an application which uses the latest entity framework together with SQL Compact with code first.
I want a zero deployment, means, on the target machine nothing except .net 4 is installed, I just copy the assemblies and everything have to work.

The requirements are just:

- Latest EF
- .Net 4.0
- Code First
- SQL Compact
- The location of the *.sdf has to be done in the code, not in the *.config file

I google for hours and try different "solutions" from several places, nothing worked. On the target machine I always have just a crash without any information whats wrong.

Did anyone know a step by step tutorial or something with met my requirements?
(Or have a working project ready to tryout?)

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post and a completed solution here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html

Comment: This I also tried, doesn't work for me. I tried the download you provide, but everything is broken when I change it back to .Net 4. It also has no code first, I found no solution how to use it with code first. And at last I was not able to change the location of the sdf file out of the code. (note too that SQl CE is not installed on the target machine, just to copy a sdf file is not the problem)

Comment: What does "everything is borken" mean? You must reinstall the EF Nuget packages, as EF has different builds for 4.0 and 4.5. And you can use ny sdf copy solution with code first, just use a connection string with |DataDirectory|. It will be the exact same solution with code first.

Comment: I download and changed it to .Net 4.0. On build the right EF packages form NuGet will be downloaded, but then I get some errors because of some invalid constraints and stuff. I want to delete the edmx file anyway, but I'm not able to change the whole project to a code first project. I can create a new object I call "Context" deriving from DbContext, but I get errors because of missing dll file (System.Data.Entity) - so on the end I'm on the same state like I created a completely new project.

Comment: The questions are: How to change the solution to code first; How to define the location of the sdf file (Like C:\MyFiles\demo.sdf); How to set the connection string out of the code; How to let it run on a machine without SQL CE installed. I'm not able to change your project in such a way

Comment: Suggest you read up on code firts! So you want to define the connection string in code? You might have given me an idea for a new blog post! Is .NET 4.0 required, or will 4.5 work?

Comment: .Net 4.0 have to be, it has to run on Windows XP too. But I think I was able to let an application from me run

Comment: I cannot answer myself in this moment, I have to wait. Here my reply: http://pastebin.com/V4MFz7Aq